# Is there a Chrome version of IE's "Every time I visit the webpage"?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser-cache

In IE, there are caching options like the following image - "Every time I visit the webpage"

Is there an equivalent setting Chrome?

I want to avoid <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following lines to the Chrome shortcut:

```
--disk-cache-size=1 --media-cache-size=1
```

I believe you can get to this by right-clicking the shortcut icon and clicking "Properties," but I haven't used Windows in a long time. This will disable Chrome's storage of temporary cache files just like you enabled for IE, but using 0 for either value may cause Chrome to crash.

I have not been able to find an option for this in the preference menu.

Also, if for some reason you are not using a Windows machine, [here is a step-by-step guide](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=6d77685d7dcbcc19&hl=en) on how to use command line options with Chrome.

— Source: [Wikipedia - Bypass Your Cache - Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache#Google_Chrome)